# Deconvoluting Raman spectras from different wavelengths

Tags: laser, spectroscopy, signal-processing, raman-spectroscopy

I am using a laser source that is wider than typical laser source for Raman spectroscopy. This mean that the full width at half maximum (FWHM) of the laser is about 5-10 nm, compared to the normal 1-3 nm.

Hypothetically, if my laser source peaks at 785 nm and has a FWHM of 10nm, this means:

Assuming that it is 10,000 units at the peak (785 nm)
Then I could expect 5,000 units per second at around 780 nm and 790 nm
The intensity of the wavelengths of 780 to 785 and 790 to 785 follows a non-linear function that I can probably characterize.
If I look at a particular wavenumber in my result:

Can I express it as the sum of overlapping Raman spectras from different wavelengths?

This implies:

`intensity2000 = SUMMATION( ... a780 * intensity780 + a781 * intensity781 + ....),`

where a780 = 0.5 and a790 = 0.5, etc

I am interested to know whether there are research done in this area that could enable me to use a wider, but much cheaper, laser source.

Is it possible to deconvolute overlapping Raman spectras from a "wide" laser source?

Comment: Depends on your signal to noise ratio. With infinite SNR one can deconvolute any signal that has non-degenerate components... but scanning 1nm with 10nm line width is probably pushing it. 3nm with 5nm line width sounds doable, your results will probably be somewhere in the middle. Make sure you understand your error propagation or you will produce some really bad results.

Comment: @CuriousOne Are there literature on how to do this? I don't want to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: Search for "spectral line fitting". There should be plenty of papers and software on the topic.

Comment: @CuriousOne Not much showing up...

Comment: You must be on a different internet than me...